# С помощью чего можно кликать, заполнять иннпуты и тп

Tags: java, парсер, cookie, htmlunit

Я пользуюсь htmlunit для парсинга, иногда мне приходится логинится в аккаунт, чтобы получать информацию, htmlunit немного багнутый, и не везде получается зайти с помощью отправки в инпут данных, либо работы с формой. Поэтому вопрос, с помощью чего я могу кликать и заполнять инпуты в связке с htmlunit, либо с чем-то другим, что парсит. Что-то слышал про куки, вроде бы их используют для этого. Если есть ссылки с примерами для htmlunit, будтье добры, скиньте)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium. 
[Что такое Selenium WebDriver?](https://habr.com/ru/post/152971/)